# to make until successful synchronous in mule 3.4

Tags: mule, mule-component

Below is a part of my mule flow

```
<until-successful objectStore-ref="ObjStreuntil" maxRetries="60"              secondsBetweenRetries="60" doc:name="Until Successful" failureExpression="#   [payload.state == 'Queued' || payload.state == 'InProgress']">
<processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
<sfdc:batch-info config-ref="Salesforce" doc:name="Salesforce">
   <sfdc:batch-info ref="#[payload]"/>
</sfdc:batch-info>
<logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</processor-chain>
</until-successful>
```

I would like my flow to wait until my batch is completed and then proceed to the next processor. I believed using processing chain will get the outcome.

But the flow doesn't work. I'm aware that until sucessfull is made synchronos in 3.5 is there any method to acheive this on 3.4.0

Any suggestions would be of great help

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal in 3.4, add a `flow-ref` or `vm:outbound-endpoint` after the batch call so the subsequent logic can be executed when the batch is done.

This is preferable to blocking the main flow thread anyways, since batch processing can take a while.

Note that you may need to add a filter after `sfdc:batch-info` if you want to process the subsequent logic only for certain return codes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Adding the flow-ref next to sfdc:batch-info doesn't work. My requirement is flow should wait until the batch is complete and proceed to check the sfdc:batch-result.Is there any other ways to do this....

Comment: If you really need to block the main flow (which sounds like a design flaw), you could use a `request-reply` to call a flow with the until-successful and wait for a response coming from within the `processor-chain`.

Comment: Request reply is not supported in Mule 3.4.0 and looks like i have to go with your first suggestion. Thank you

Comment: This is not true: request-reply is available since Mule 3.0.0 (https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/tree/mule-3.0.0/core/src/main/java/org/mule/routing/requestreply). Here is its doc for 3.4.0: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-RequestReply

Comment: I was not able to find request reply scope in my studio, may be a update is required and also <http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Request-Reply+Scope> shows request reply scope is available only for 3.5(Current)

Comment: Studio can be confusing at times. I ensure you that you can use `until-successful` with 3.4.0, CE or EE.